# ATXmega phantom breakpoint while debugging

Tags: debugging, embedded, breakpoints, atmel, iar

I have an ATXmega that I am writing code for. I have IAR embedded workbench and an AVR ONE! that connects to the circuit board with a PDI.

When debugging, I am able to get the chip to halt. That is, the system clock will halt, as though it has hit a break point. The IAR debugging GUI will make no change when this happens; I click 'reset' and then 'go' and IAR tells me the CPU is running normally, but the chip itself thinks a breakpoint has been hit. If I click 'pause' and then 'play' again, the chip will continue without issue. This state happens much more reliably when there are breakpoints set elsewhere in the code.

I have a debug signal on a spare GPIO pin that toggles every clock cycle, producing a signal that is half the frequency of the external crystal. When the chip enters this halted state, both the clock and debug signals cease.

I have been able to remove and add code to the start of main, and the program will halt in different places, but it will always halt after the same amount of time (seemingly. I have not been able to fully confirm that the time or number of clock cycles is consistent).

This only ever happens when debugging, never when the chip is running with no debugger. I have replaced the chip, I have given the same program to a colleague's computer and used his toolchain to program my board, and I have commented out away almost my entire code, and the error persists. My colleagues have never seen this behaviour before.

One final thing: we have a circuit that pulls a few pins high when given a ~8v signal. These are the only pins that are pulled high. The halted/error state has only been seen when this ~8v signal is present.

What's going on here? Has anyone else ever seem this sort of phantom breakpoint?

Edit: I would like to add that we have removed the circuit that pulls those pins high and we still see the behaviour.

Comment: You suggest it may be related to some "~8V signal" but give no information about what that signal is applied to - since none of the ATXMega pins can tolerate a signal of that level, it is not at all clear what you are doing there.  And _"a few pins"_?  How about telling us _which pins_?  That is probably relevant.  If it is not related to the code you are executing, it is probably off-topic here and perhaps https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ might be more appropriate.